# How to find other Ramanujan-type continued fractions

Tags: continued-fractions

In a letter to G.H Hardy on January $13^{\text{th}}$, Ramanujan posted this interesting continued fraction:$$\cfrac {1}{1+\cfrac {e^{-2\pi}}{1+\cfrac {e^{-4\pi}}{1+\cfrac {e^{-6\pi}}{1+\cfrac {e^{-8\pi}}{1+\ddots}}}}}=\left(\sqrt{\dfrac {5+\sqrt5}2}-\dfrac {1+\sqrt5}2\right)\sqrt[5]{e^{2\pi}}\tag1$$
I find this interesting that an infinite continued fraction can be represented by a finite nested radical!

> **Question:**

1. Is there a way to generate similar identities to $(1)$?
2. How did Ramanujan come up with $(1)$ in the first place?

Comment: Identity (1) is immediately obvious to the most casual observer.  $$ $$As long as that observer is Ramanujan.

Comment: See [Rogers-Ramanujan continued fraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rogers%E2%80%93Ramanujan_continued_fraction).

Comment: ... and the references there.  In particular, you might look at Berndt's book "Ramanujan's Notebooks: Part III".

Comment: The fact that it is on January 13th or February 29th without knowing the year isn't that important, don't you think :) ?

Comment: @RobertIsrael Do you happen to know what page in Ramanujan's Notebook?

Comment: In particular, page 79.  But much of chapter 16 will be relevant.